# passing results of a query into another query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to run a query like below

```
SELECT  `loginname`, `id`, `locality`, `wherefrom` 
FROM `Volley` JOIN `register` ON loginname=username 
WHERE CONCAT_WS('', wherefrom,locality) LIKE '%$search%'
```

from this result i need to take id and pass it to the other query to check that id exist in another table like below.

```
SELECT IF(EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM `likes` 
                 WHERE Volleyid = '20'),1,0)
```

Can i combine this into a single query? For the first one i may get more that 1 rows.  I tried and got the results of first query into a array but i am not able to get that particular value from array.

```
$data = array();

for ($x = 0; $x < mysqli_num_rows($query1); $x++)
{
 $data[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1);
}
```

Comment: Read about subqueries (that aren't scalar subqueries). (Also using select expressions as union operands.) Read the grammar for select statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IF(EXISTS(SELECT * From 
(
SELECT  `loginname`,
        `id`,
        `locality`,
        `wherefrom`,
         Volleyid  
         FROM `Volley` 
JOIN `register` 
ON loginname=username 
WHERE CONCAT_WS('', wherefrom,locality) LIKE '%$search%'
) AS T1
WHERE Volleyid = '20'),1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery with IN clause (i think what you what it ś that Volleyid it's equal to id):

```
SELECT IF(EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM `likes` 
                 WHERE Volleyid IN 
                      (SELECT  `id` 
                       FROM `Volley` JOIN `register` ON loginname=username 
                       WHERE CONCAT_WS('', wherefrom,locality) LIKE '%$search%')),1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get `loginname`, `id`, `locality`, `wherefrom` columns in the first query alongside with the 1 or 0 flag checked against table `likes` in single result set. You can write query that looks like this:

```
SELECT v.*, IF(l.Volleyid IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) as existFlag
FROM 
(SELECT `loginname`, `id`, `locality`, `wherefrom`
FROM `Volley`
JOIN `register` ON loginname=username
WHERE CONCAT_WS('', wherefrom,locality) LIKE '%$search%') AS v
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT Volleyid
FROM `likes`) l ON v.id = l.Volleyid;
```